# Retrieving function pointers from container

Tags: c++, containers, function-pointers

I think this will make more sense if I put the code first:

I have a member variable defined as such:

```
std::queue<void (*)()> fptrs;
```

...and am trying to pop a pointer back out of it like this:

```
void (*f)() = fptrs.pop();
```

The 'alert' I get is this:

```
Assigning to 'void (*)()' from incompatible type 'void'
```

It seems that I'm not putting function pointers into my queue, or they're popping back out magically transformed. Either way, I'm not sure how to fix this, and I've fiddled with it for a bit.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::queue::pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) returns `void`. You need a call to [`std::queue::front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front), followed by one to `std::queue::pop()`.

I would suggest using a `typedef` for the function pointer, for the sake of readability.

Comment: I knew I'd feel stupid when this got answered. Thanks a lot, I'll read the docs better next time!

Comment: @Tyler The interface is a bit non-intuitive. If you're interested, it is like this for reasons of *exception safety*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*pFun)();

void fun1(){ printf("fun1\n"); }
void fun2(){ printf("fun2\n"); }
int main()
{
    queue<pFun> d;
    d.push(fun1);
    d.push(fun2);

    pFun fun = d.front();
    fun();
}
```